# How can I separate templates by data in jbuilder

Tags: ruby, sinatra, padrino, jbuilder

I want to make following data with jbuilder.
How can I make jbuilder separated?

```
data: [{
  type: "top"
  logo: "logo.png"
  title: "title"
  },{
  type: "nav"
  background: "bg.png"
  content: "<div> Welcome </div>"
  },{
  type: "footer"
  content: "Copyright: xx"
  }
]
```

I did it like that, but couldn't running

data.jbuilder

```
json.set! :result do
  json.array! data do |item|
     case item.type
     when 'top'
       json.partial! '_top', item: item
     when 'nav'
       json.partial! '_nav', item: item
     when 'footer'
       json.partial! '_footer', item: item
     else 
       return nil
  end
end
```

_top.jbuilder

```
json.logo   item.logo
json.title  item.title
```

_nav.jbuilder

```
json.background item.background
json.content    item.content
```

_footer.jbuilder

```
json.content item.content
```

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you call partials, `_` is not needed you just give the path if it is in different folder or name if in same folder.

try

```
json.partial! 'top', item: item
json.partial! 'nav', item: item
json.partial! 'footer', item: item
```